# Maximum concurrent http connections for same domain between two servers

Tags: http, concurrency, server, limit

I have a Tomcat Server running which connects to another Tableau server. I need to make about 25 GET calls from Tomcat to Tableau. Now I am trying to thread this and let each thread create its own HTTP connection object and make the call. On my local system (Tomcat local, Tableau is remote), I notice that in this case each of my thread takes about 10 seconds average, so in total 10 seconds.

However, if I do this sequentially, each request takes 2 seconds, thereby total of 50.

My doubt is, when making requests in parallel, why does each take more than 2 seconds when it takes just 2 when done sequentially?

Does this have anything to do with maximum concurrent connections to same domain from one client (browser)? But here the request is going from my Tomcat server, not browser.

If yes, what is the default rule and is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 0):

In  my opinion, its most likely [Context Switching Overhead](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/costs.html) that the system has to go through for each request and that is why you see longer times for individual requests ( compared to one sequential thread ) but significant gain in overall processing.

It makes sense to go for parallel processing when **Context Switching Overhead** is negligible compared to time taken in overall activity.